# Как использовать функции из Windows RT в своем проекте

Tags: c#, windows, dll

Есть пространство имен `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`. Как я понял оно есть только в Windows RT. В нем есть класс `WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions`. Не совсем понятно как его использовать в своем проекте

Comment: Это пространство имён доступно только для проектов Windows Store.

Comment: ммм. а как быть? мб есть вариант его заюзать у себя?

Comment: Посмотрите [эту](http://www.davidmoore.info/blog/2014/10/17/walkthrough-using-winrt-libraries-from-a-windows-desktop-application/) ссылку